# ocultando o id a url LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

Bom dia galera, alguém me ajuda estou tentando esconder o id.

como aparece: http://localhost:8000/admin/cliente/editar/**1**

quero que fica assim http://localhost:8000/admin/cliente/editar

**sem mostrar o id**

button

```
<a href="{{route('admin.editar.cliente', ['id' => $cliente->id])}}" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

controller

```
 public function edit($id)
{
    $id = base64_decode($id);
    $cliente = Cliente::with('user')->where('id', $id)->first();//pega primeiro resultado
    return view('cliente.editar', compact('cliente'));//pega os cliente clicado

}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('cliente/editar/{id}', 'ClienteController@edit')->name('admin.editar.cliente');
```

Comment: Você pode utilizar Hashids. Segue o link como referência: <https://coderwall.com/p/gt1zkg/laravel-hidden-id>

Comment: E ao acessar `/admin/cliente/editar`, como saberá qual cliente deseja editar?

Comment: eu só queria ocultar, não ficar mostrando pro usuário @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Sim, mas a sua aplicação precisará buscar esse valor de algum lugar para saber qual registro buscar no banco. Hoje ela busca da URL, se for tirá-la dali precisará buscar de outro lugar.

Answer (score -1):

Uma opção seria armazenar o id em uma variável de sessão
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
ai você redirecionaria a url
header('Location: cliente/editar');
nessa rota você deverá realizar uma verificação caso sua função contenha $_SESSION['id']
caso contenha você utilizará ela na sua função
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
lembre-se de encerrar a variável após seu uso
unset($_SESSION['id']);